# How do I change shape of div and make the paragraphs wrap around it using CSS?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I have an image that I want to angle/rotate in a paragraph and make the text wrap around the image. What is the best css approach in this? do I use the background-image property? or do I place an and change the shape of the image? Need help. What is the best multi-browser easy approach? I tried this, but it does not work with good text wrapping.

```
.shaped {
width: 433px;
height: 344px;
background: #1eff00;
float:left;
padding: 5rem;
transform: rotate(-20deg);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}2
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code. Please read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property. (Note its partial browser support, though.)